# Java Multi Threading priority relation with start() method

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-priority

My code and output are as below :-

My question is that the priority of main thread and thread t4 is 9 and that of thread t is 5 then why line 1 to 4 (marked in output) is coming before line 5 i.e. why t.start() gets priority over t4.start() which will be executed by main thread which has priority of 9.

Main thread priority is 9 so first t4.start() should get executed but then why t.start() is getting executed first ?

And if I reverse the order of calling start method i.e. if I call in order t4.start() and then t.start() then output is as expected.

**Output**

```
5

5

Main Thread Priority :9

5

Calling MyRunnable2 from main....9

Child Class                                - line 1

Child Class                                - line 2

End of Child loop                                - line 3

Calling MyRunnable2 from MyThread                - line 4

MyRunnable2 Class....Main....9                   - line 5

MyRunnable2 Class....From MyThread run....5
```

**CODE :-**

```
public class ThreadPriority 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        MyThread t = new MyThread();
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getPriority());
        System.out.println(t.getPriority());
        t.setName("From MyThread");

        Thread.currentThread().setPriority(9);

        System.out.println("Main Thread Priority :" + Thread.currentThread().getPriority());
        System.out.println(t.getPriority());



        MyRunnable2 r4 = new MyRunnable2();
        Thread t4 = new Thread(r4,"Main");
        System.out.println("Calling MyRunnable2 from main"+"...."+t4.getPriority());

        t.start();
        t4.start();
    }

}


class MyRunnable2 implements Runnable
{
    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println("MyRunnable2 Class"+"...."+Thread.currentThread().getName()+"...."+Thread.currentThread().getPriority());

    }
}
class MyThread extends Thread
{
    public void run()
    {
        for (int i=0;i<2;i++)
            System.out.println("Child Class");

        System.out.println("End of Child loop");

        MyRunnable2 r2 = new MyRunnable2();
        Thread t2 = new Thread(r2,"From MyThread run");
        System.out.println("Calling MyRunnable2 from MyThread");
        t2.start();

    }
```

Comment: Because priority is a kinda broken concept for Java threads. These numbers are a recommendation to the operating system. What really happens depends on implementation/os.

Comment: Hi @GhostCat Does that means my understanding is correct and the above behavior is an anomaly ?

Comment: No it means that you should not use thread priority to determine the order of execution. If your code depends on thread priority as a requirement to run correctly, it is probably broken. You should use synchronization or `java.util.concurrent` if it matters to you.

Comment: Using thread priority to determine scheduling order might have worked in single CPU machines (where only one thread can execute at any time). Since most of the current computers have multiple cores and are therefore able to run multiple threads in parallel the concept of thread priority is even more useless.

Answer (score 0):

t4 priority is higher and its doesn't mean t4 will finish first,Furthermore
 jvm ask OS for threads and all priorities sets in deep layer of OS, 
you are just set a recommendation,it depends on many things!

Answer (score 0):

The higher the integer, the higher the priority.
At any given time, when multiple threads are ready to be executed, the runtime system chooses the runnable thread with the highest priority for execution.
Only when that thread stops, yields, or becomes not runnable for some reason will a lower priority thread start executing.

If two threads of the same priority are waiting for the CPU, the scheduler chooses one of them to run in a round-robin fashion.

Rule of thumb : ***At any given time, the highest priority thread is running. However, this is not a guaranteed. The thread scheduler may choose to run a lower priority thread to avoid starvation. For this reason, use priority only to affect scheduling policy for efficiency purposes. Do not rely on thread priority for algorithm correctness.***

I hope the above information clarifies your query.